# Unwanted bone rotation around cursor

Tags: bones, transforms, 3d-cursor

I have an rig set up with a control armature, and a deform armature.
I have some control bones that I use for IK constraints.

When I try to rotate some of these control bones, instead of rotating around the head of the bone as the pivot point, they rotate around the cursor - changing not just the angle of the bone, but also the position - which I DO NOT want.

I have made more than one version of my rig, saved as I went along. In an older version the rig has several problems, but at least there, when I rotate the bones, they rotate around their own heads as the pivot points, not around the cursor.

I want to be able to rotate the bones to change their angles, but not their positions.

Does anyone know what setting I may have unintentionally altered that has lead to the bones rotating around the cursor instead of their positions?

(the bones are parented to other bones in both versions, with "keep offset" - I do not understand why in one file, they keep their position as parented to the parent bone, and rotate around the head, whilst in the other, they rotate around the cursor and change the distance from the parent bone.)

Comment: instead of marking the question as "Solved" please write an answer to your own question and mark that as accepted. Otherwise your question is still considered as unanswered... please read: [Can I answer my own question?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and also the links on this page to understand how this site works: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
I found a solution to this myself when I compared my older file with my newer file.

I unchecked the "manipulate around centre points only" box (the one with the three small dots and the arrows in the image below), then clicked on the menu to the left of that, and changed the pivot point from "3d cursor" to "median point". This worked perfectly to solve this problem!

[image: blender pivot point menu]